# Delete an element, that was created with document.createElement

Tags: javascript, dom

I am creating this link to just download a file from fetchApi request.
What I want to know, how to delete this element after click on this.
I tried giving id to the element like: `tempLink.id='someId'` and then something like:

```
let element = document.getElementById('someid')
element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
```

Here's the code:

```
 const tempLink = document.createElement('a');
 tempLink.href = csvURL;
 tempLink.setAttribute('download', selectedDocument?.fileName);
 tempLink.click();
```

Comment: you just need to execute the remove method after programmatically clicking the link like so `tempLink.remove()` (this will work if you append the link element, if you do not append it, set to null)

Comment: How about `tempLink.parentNode.removeChild(tempLink)`?

Comment: @RobBailey Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null

Comment: @AngelSalazar Thanks, tempLink.remove() works.

Comment: lordcarnisser - `tempLink.remove();` is a no-op if it's not in the DOM anywhere, which it isn't in your code above (which is why @RobBailey's code didn't work).

Comment: @AngelSalazar - [`remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) doesn't do anything if the element isn't in the DOM. Calling it is a no-op in the OP's code above, since it's not in the DOM.

Comment: if you care performance, important to use `URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);` this will remove reference for that link and this more important than delete the link which not effect performance much

Answer (score 1):

If you never put the element in the DOM, then only your `tempLink` constant has a reference to it. When that constant goes out of scope, the DOM element will be reclaimed by the browser. You don't need to do anything explicit to make that happen.

---

Slightly off to the side of your question, but I should note that Firefox ignores the click if you never put the element in the DOM and release your reference to it right away — or at least, it did last I checked, so unless it's changed relatively recent... You may want to append it somewhere, wait a bit, and remove it. The workaround looks like this:

```
// WORKAROUND for Firefox's ignoring the click
const tempLink = document.createElement('a');
tempLink.href = csvURL;
tempLink.setAttribute('download', selectedDocument?.fileName);
document.body.appendChild(tempLink);
tempLink.click();
setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(tempLink); // On modern browsers you can use `tempLink.remove();`
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you won't put the tempLink on the page, then you won't be able to delete it, because it exists just in your file. If you want to append it somewhere, you need to do

document.querySelector("Insert here where you want it to append").append(tempLink)

and now you can delete it, with

document.querySelector("id of the templink").remove()

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change style display of the element to none.

Comment: element1.style.display = "none"; //  element1 is element which you want to delete.